# Create strings from MySQL entries

Tags: php, mysql, database, content-management-system

I'm trying to automate adding pages in my simple CMS and, not being a big user of PHP, can't work out how I would get a column from my MySQL database and create a set of strings from it. I'll explain.

```
$home=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM data WHERE callsign='home'"); //**

$num=mysql_num_rows($home);
$i=0;
while ($i < $num) {
 $f1=mysql_result($home,$i,"code"); //**
 $i++;
}
switch($_GET['page'])  {
case '#home' : $page = $f1; break; //**
}
echo $page;
```

How would I create the strings and variables on the lines marked with an asterisk for each entry in a column on a MySQL database?

Comment: i think it should be **$f1=mysql_result($home,$i);**..

Comment: your question isn't very clear. Assuming this code works it seems it would return a string.

Comment: @mithunsatheesh - I think he's looking for a field named `code` but you're right, I doubt that will work. The third argument should be numeric. The while loop is useless as well

Comment: Yeah, the field on the database is called "code"

Comment: @Cfreak: sorry dude. u r right. but the 3rd argument is not absolutely necessary.

Comment: @mithunsatheesh - yes it's not required but in this case because he's selecting * he wants that particular column. Apparently a named field is valid: http://us2.php.net/mysql_result

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what you mean by "variables" and "strings" from the database but here's how I would right this. Note that I'm using [PDO](http://php.net/PDO) because the `mysql_*` functions are deprecated.

```
// this is how you connect with PDO
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:dbname=yourdbname;host=yourhost','youruser','yourpassword');

// you can name the column from the database itself. This is much faster
// also the ? is a placeholder. We'll pass the value on execute()
// this prevents SQL Injection attacks.
$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT code FROM data WHERE callsign=?");

// use try { } catch { } to detect errors
try {
    $sth->execute( array($_GET['page']) );
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    die( $e->getMessage() );
}

// now you can fetch(). This returns the first row as an array. list() names the only variable in it
list($code) = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM); 

$sth->closeCursor(); // close the cursor or you'll have problems reusing the db handle

print $code; // output is a string
```